# How do I append an element to a form inside a Shadowbox

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, textarea, shadowbox

I'm trying to append a textarea to a small form that exists within a Shadowbox. The Shadowbox is called from a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Upload" onClick="uploadImageSB();">
```

The javascript to invoke the Shadowbox is written as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tribnet_2013/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Shadowbox.init({

        });

        function uploadImageSB() {

            // shadowbox for image upload
            Shadowbox.open({
                content:    'http://mydomain.com/cgi-bin/photo.cgi',
                player:     'iframe',
                title:      'Image Upload',
                height:     200,
                width:      500,
                options: {
                    onOpen: function() {

                        var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
                        var content = ed.save();

                        var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
                        ta.textContent = content;
                        ta.name = 'editor';
                        ta.value = ta.textContent;

                        var form = document.getElementById('photoForm');
                        form.appendChild(ta);
                    }
                }
            });

        };

    </script>
```

As you can see, I'm also grabbing the contents of my TinyMCE editor from the same page that called the Shadowbox (this part is working fine).

The form in the Shadowbox looks like this:

```
<form id="photoForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="photoForm" action="[% base_url %]/cgi-bin/photo.cgi" method="post" target="_parent">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tr><td colspan="4" style="height: 50px;"></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 175px;"><label>Image Name:</label></td>
            <td style="width: 275px;"><input type="text" name="image_name" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="4" style="height: 20px;"></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 175px;"><label>Load Image:</label></td>
            <td style="width: 275px;"><input type="file" name="image_file" size="20"></td>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="4" style="height: 20px;"></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 175px;"><label>Press Button to Upload:</td>
            <td style="width: 275px;"><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload"></td>
            <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="4" style="height: 20px;"></td></tr>

    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="function" value="photo_upload_process">

</form>
```

The form in the shadow box is also working fine. Note that I have a target="_parent" in the form tag. I'm not sure that's right ... I think it prevents my Shadowbox from closing properly (need help with this).

What I'd like to do is ... take the markup in my content variable and ...

1) dynamically create a textarea  called "ta"
2) put the content into ta
3) append ta to the form in the Shadowbox
4) submit the form

Everything works except the append. I've tried to do this using the Shadowbox options onOpen and onClose. It fails. **Probably because the form is in an iframe!**

I've tried to deal with the iframe too, but I can't get it to work. I thought I could make the Shadowbox object a child of the page that contains the iframe using:

```
window.parent.Shadowbox.open({})
```

But I can't get that to work either. I'm a little out of my depth ... would really appreciate some help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadowbox's iframe id is `sb-player`, so you should access the iframe content.

Pure javascript method,

```
options: {
  onFinish: function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('sb-player');
    iframe.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var ed = tinymce.activeEditor; // get editor instance
        var content = ed.save(); // get the editor content
        var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
        ta.textContent = content;
        ta.name = 'editor';
        ta.value = ta.textContent;
        var iframeContent = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
        var form = iframeContent.getElementById('photoForm');
        form.appendChild(ta);
    },true);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, the JS won't run. It doesn't seem to like this line `var iframeContent = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;` I tried using one or the other since they are the same ... no joy.

Comment: Does the iframe have same domain with parent window, if it's different you can't access iframe content? And do you have a live example?

Comment: Yes, the domains are the same. My Perl CGI's are using TT2 (Template Toolkit) so there are different wrappers and content pages involved, but everything shares the same domain. The form in the SB uses photo_wrapper.tt and a content page called photo.tt. The SB is called from a page with a different wrapper and content page ... but this shouldn't matter, right? Unfortunately, everything is behind a secure access area ...

Comment: I will modify the code to grant you access if you like ... let me know.

Comment: Yes, I would look at, if it's possible.

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake, `iframeContent.document.getElementById("photoForm")` should be `iframeContent.getElementById("photoForm")`. I updated my answer. It seems to be working now. Live demo helped me to find out the problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I made the change. Unfortunately, the content from the editor is not getting passed to the CGI. If you enter some text in the editor window, and then try to upload a image and press the "Upload" button in the SB form, everything should be sent to the CGI where I currently report out the image name and the content of the editor. The image name shows up, but not the editor contents. I noticed FF reports this JS error ... TypeError: form is null when I open the Shadowbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30349/discussion-between-ocanal-and-mysilmaril)

Comment: Note that under options I have "onFinish" ... is this right? If I change it to "onOpen", FF will report iframe is null ...